# How to import ogre .mesh & .skeleton files in blender

Tags: mesh, import

Using blender I generated .mesh & .skeleton files for use in OGRE. In OGRE I used skeletal animation to modify the skeleton. Using the modified skeleton & the original mesh I want to get the new mesh.

MY question is how can import the .mesh & .skeleton(modified) into blender.
Also how do I get/save the modified mesh in blender?

Comment: You can use this addon to import .mesh but not .skeleton . The link is provided by the creator of Kenshi https://www.lofigames.com/phpBB3/download/file.php?id=5037